# View Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server License Count

Tags: windows-server-2000, licensing

How can I view how many Terminal Server licenses are installed on a Windows Server 2000 machine? Normally you would look in Administrative tools -> Terminal Server Licensing, but there is not an entry for that in the start menu.

I know there are either many CALs installed on this device or some type of Terminal server on the network supplying the licenses. I can see in the Terminal Services Manager that there are around 10 people RDP-ing to the server, so they have to be installed somewhere, and there should be a way of knowing how many licenses there are.

**Update:** I can not install programs on the machine. It is a client server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this machine is actually the license server?  Perhaps the license server is installed on some other machine.  If it is the license server, and you are simply missing the shortcut then you could try starting up the MMC, and adding the terminal service licensing snap-in.

Comment: That is what I was thinking might have been the case. Thank you very much for this information. I just wanted to make sure that was correct before I counted that server as not having any extra terminal server licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying out Terminal Services License Server Viewer.

Terminal Services License Server Viewer (LSView) is a graphical tool that displays information useful for monitoring and logging the status of all available Terminal Services license servers in the current domain and current site of the computer.

Overview
Terminal Services License Server Viewer (LSView) is a GUI tool that displays information about all available Terminal Services license servers in the current domain and current site of the computer. It is useful for monitoring and logging the status of license servers.

LSView displays the following information:

The names of all license servers in the current domain and site. This includes new license servers added to the domain and all license servers from the current Active Directory Site within the domain.
The types of all license servers in the domain. There are two types of license servers, Enterprise License Servers and Domain License Servers. The Workgroup License Server type for workgroups is Domain. It is important to know the type of license server when troubleshooting.
The date and time each license server is available. By default, LSView updates server availability every five minutes.

This update addresses the following issue:
Added support to log discovery operations from Windows 2000 and Windows Server 2003 License Servers

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12620

Comment: The only problem with your suggestion (installing a program) would be that this is on a virtual client machine, therefore I cannot install programs on the server. Thank you very much for the great suggestion though!

Comment: Install it on any computer in their domain.  Or simply extract the lsview.exe and place copy it anywhere and run it.